# xpath to fetch menu from a node's menu's parent sibling

Tags: xml, xpath

i have an xml structure :

```
<Pages>          <!--This is the root node-->

    <Home>
        <url>...</url>
        <menu>
            <item>Help</item>
            <item>About</item>
            <item>Contact</item>
        </menu>
    </Home>

    <Help>               
          <menu>                           <!--i need to select this if its parent(Help) is listed in Home/menu/item above-->
            <item>Business Help</item>
            <item>Web Help</item>
            <item>Tour Help</item>
          </menu>
    </Help> 

    <About>            
          <menu>                          <!--And Or select this if its parent(About) is listed in Home/menu/item above-->
            <item>About us</item>
            <item>About our food</item>
            <item>About our people</item>
        </menu>
    </About>

    <Contact>                              <!--And Or select this if its listed in Home/menu/item above-->
          ...
             and so on...
          ...
    </Contact>

</Pages>
```

i need an xpath expression that selects the menu child of any page (e.g Help/menu, About/menu)
that has its menu parent name (page name, e.g Help, About, or Contact) listed in Home/menu/item

any help will be greately appreciated. thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way :

```
/Pages/*[name()=preceding-sibling::Home/menu/item]/menu
```

Comment: Compare this XPath and the one in my answer to your previous question, you should be able to make sense of the two XPath :)

Comment: learnt alot. not gota give up until am good in xpath. thanks.

Comment: But How about this one:
/Pages/*/*[name = 'menu' and name(..) = parent::*[preceding-sibling::Home/menu/item] ]

why didnt it work ? or am i doing something bizzare ?

Comment: @OsagieOdigie that's close to a working expression, you only need to change the part *after* `name(..) = ` to : `parent::*/preceding-sibling::Home/menu/item`

Comment: Did just as you said, seems like what should work, supprisingly it didnt. i thought in your xpression: parent::*/preceding-sibling::Home/menu/item, parent::* will return menu's parent node(Home) and then / will fall back to the Home's children again instead of sibling. what do you think ?